# Passing dynamically allocated array from function to another fuction

Tags: c++

I am new in C++. I want to make program which is creating all possible words from array. The problem is I don't know how to pass value of array from one function to another.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void insertArray(int sizeOfArray);
void outputArray(int sizeOfArray, char * aray);

int main(){
    insertArray(5);

    return 0;
}

void insertArray(int sizeOfArray){
    char value;
    char *arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout << "Input letter number: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> value;

        if(value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
            arrayOfletters[i] = value;
        else {
            cout << "Inputed value is wrong. Try again!" << endl;
            i--;
        }
    }
}

void outputArray(int sizeOfArray, char * array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        cout << array[i];
}
```

Now I want to pass values from `insertArray` function to `outputArray` function to check how it works.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: In C++, You should use `std::vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways you can do it

1. Let your insert function return an array.

   ```
   char* insertArray(int sizeOfArray){
       char value;
       char *arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
       for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
           cout << "Input letter number: " << i+1 << endl;
           cin >> value;

           if(value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
               arrayOfletters[i] = value;
           else {
               cout << "Inputed value is wrong. Try again!" << endl;
               i--;
           }
       }
       return arrayOfletters;
   }
   ```
2. Pass the array with parameter, since it is a pointer, the content is shared inside / outside the array:

   ```
   void insertArray(int sizeOfArray, char*& arrayOfletters){
   char value;
   arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
       cout << "Input letter number: " << i+1 << endl;
       cin >> value;

       if(value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
           arrayOfletters[i] = value;
       else {
           cout << "Inputed value is wrong. Try again!" << endl;
           i--;
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Both should works

Comment: The second one does not work, because you'd have to pass a pointer to a pointer. Note that you overwrite `char* arrayOfletters` and assign `new char[...]` to it.

Comment: @StephanLechner Hmm. Correct, we can pass it by reference then

Comment: What is the name of first solution? I want to read more about it.

Comment: @KonradDos I don't think it have any fancier name than `return an object`? Any function in c++ are allowed to have a return value.

Comment: I am surprised of * symbol next to type of function. Btw. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with old style arrays. Just use a `std::vector` (or `std::array`) and pass it like you would any other variable.

If `insertArray` just returned a vector of values you could capture that in a variable and then pass it to `outputArray`.

```
auto val = inputArray(...);
outputArray(val);
```

Comment: This should be a comment - it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: "Don't bother with old C style arrays", why old ? In C this is not old.

Comment: If this is for learning purposes it's important to know the backing behind std::vector.

Comment: @Stargateur "old" as in "there are newer and better alternatives available (`std::array` and `std::vector`) that are superior in every way) also, this is C++, *not* C.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Very opinion based... plus this is a part of C++ now. So you sentence should be "Don't bother with old C++ style arrays". thank to understand my point.

Comment: @Stargateur tweaked the text a bit.

Comment: @Stargateur built-in arrays are commonly called "C-style" arrays because, VLAs aside, they work the same as their C counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to return the array allocated and filled in `insertArray` as return value. Note that you will also have to free the memory allocated in `insertArray`. You'd adapt your program as follows:

```
char* insertArray(int sizeOfArray);
void outputArray(int sizeOfArray, char * aray);

int main(){
    char* array = insertArray(5);
    outputArray(5, array);
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}

char* insertArray(int sizeOfArray){
    char value;
    char *arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
    ...
    return arrayOfLetters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call outputArray from within the insertArray function as follows:

```
void insertArray(int sizeOfArray){
    char value;
    char *arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout << "Input letter number: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> value;

        if(value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
            arrayOfletters[i] = value;
        else {
            cout << "Inputed value is wrong. Try again!" << endl;
            i--;
        }
    }

    outputArray(sizeOfArray, arrayOfletters);
    delete[] arrayOfletters;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to do both from main, you must return the pointer to the array you allocated in insertArray so you can use it from main:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

char *insertArray(int sizeOfArray);
void outputArray(int sizeOfArray, char * aray);

int main(){
    char *pArray = insertArray(5);
    outputArray(sizeOfArray, pArray);
    delete[] pArray;
    return 0;
}

char *insertArray(int sizeOfArray){
    char value;
    char *arrayOfletters  = new char[sizeOfArray];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
        cout << "Input letter number: " << i+1 << endl;
        cin >> value;

        if(value >= 'a' && value <= 'z' || value >= 'A' && value <= 'Z')
            arrayOfletters[i] = value;
        else {
            cout << "Inputed value is wrong. Try again!" << endl;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arrayOfletters;
}

void outputArray(int sizeOfArray, char * array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
        cout << array[i];
}
```

Comment: You forget to call `delete[]`.

Comment: That's why using RAII object avoids this kind of problems (as `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, `vector<char>` or `std::string`)

Comment: Oh, agreed there are much better ways to do this in C++, I was trying to stick to the existing code as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `arrayOfLetters`--this is pointing to the array in memory--back to your main, and then pass it as an argument to your next function, like such:

`char* myCharArray = insertArray(5);
outputArray(5, myCharArray)`

IMPORTANT:
Make sure you call a `delete[] myCharArray` somewhere in a function or in your main or you are going to leak memory.